# 500 Internal Server Error for addtype in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, asp.net

In reference to the accepted answer in [php website to aspx .net website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464141/php-website-to-aspx-net-website). Creating a new post since that post was over-loaded with comments.

.htaccess file 
`AddType application/x-httpd-php .aspx`

`AllowOverride AuthConfig` in apache config file.

trying to parse php in the aspx page. 
index.html / index. aspx

`Hi, This is the index file. OK!

<?echo "PHP working";?>`

Getting this error in log file.
`Add type not allowed here.`

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The overall server config is probably setup to restrict certain commands from .htaccess files. You probably need to edit the server config or talk with someone who can.

Comment: THe server error log shows the same. `Add type not allowed here.`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need the `FileInfo` override. `AuthConfig` is unnecessary for this purpose, but if you need it there, the result is:

```
AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo
```

Comment: As per the Apache docs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype